# Update Map in hazelcast without overriding it

Tags: hazelcast

I am using `Map<String , String>` data structure to store my values in hazelcast . My values look like this after storing it in hazelcast.
I am using this structure `IMap<String, Map<String, String>`

`key  value`

`key1 {FNAME=Stev, LNAME =Austin ACTIVE_STATUS=1}`

`key2 {FNAME=John, LNAME =Cena ACTIVE_STATUS=1}`

`key3 {FNAME=Rock, LNAME =Johnson ACTIVE_STATUS=1}`

My Requirement : I have to update FNAME field value without retrieving whole Map and again overriding it.

I tried it using put and replace method but it is overriding whole map value.

Answer (score 3):

Hazelcast wasn't designed as a generic Map implementation. It is coarse-grained. It serializes and deserializes the whole value treating it like a database record. You should be using a normal class/bean instead of the String to String map anyway. Then it'll use less memory, especially if you implement your own serialization. It'd also allow queries, sorting, and generally make everything cleaner. The overhead is pretty minimal in that case.

Comment: In my case i am putting different types of records in single map. Also for a particular type, i don't have fixed number of fields , so can not make class/bean. It's like i am defining my fields on the go.

Comment: That's easy. Hazelcast maps are heterogeneous. You still need to develop a clean hierarchical OOP model instead of "typeless" maps. There is a number of ways to model "optional" and "variable" fields in OOP: polymorphism, aggregation, etc. Treat Hazelcast as your database. Keep your model elegant and clean - and you won't need any workarounds.

Comment: It would be great for me, if you could provide me an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into using EntryProcessor, you'll still deserialize the whole map but it will happen on the node that owns the key of your map, so you miss the network roundtrip for the value-map. Otherwise I have to say, not possible.

You might want to use multiple IMaps and just store references (names) of other IMaps in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using in-memory-format as an OBJECT and Entry processor.