# Update field in Map's value in hazelcast without completely overriding a struct

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a struct in C++

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    bool male;
    int32_t age;
};
```

and built a IMap<int, Person> and fill it with values.

```
auto map = hz.get_map("map").get();
auto p1 = Person{"Mike", true, 10};
auto p2 = Person{"Maria", false, 15};
map->put(1, p1).get();
map->put(2, p2).get();
//
p2.age = 18;
//
// Some code here to update Maria's age...
```

How to update age of Maria without fully rewriting a `p2` struct?

This example is too naive but if the `Person` struct has many fields of different types (POD, vectors, etc) then full overriding/serialization becomes an expensive operation.

Small example of code would be greatly appreciated.

This question is related to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215054/update-map-in-hazelcast-without-overriding-it) which has no answer with a clue.

Answer (score 1):

If it's simple update, something like

```
UPDATE person SET age = 55 WHERE name = 'Maria'
```

might be enough.

For more complex needs and you have Java coding ability, then a server side [EntryProcessor Java](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.3.2/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/EntryProcessor.html) / [EntryProcessor C++](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client/tree/v5.3.0/examples/distributed-map/entry-processor) is specifically designed for in-situ updates.
It's a function invoked by the C++ client that runs on the Java server.